# What is SPF error, and how do I resolve it?

Tags: email, gmail, spf

I am the admin for a business account hosted on gmail and my users are complaining that they cannot send emails to a particular address. The emails always bounce. However, sending an email to any another email address works. The receiver, says he can get emails from everyone else.

The bounce notification says the email was rejected due to an SPF(Sender Policy frameworks) error. I am not aware what I can do to resolve this or where I can resolve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Until seconds ago I had no idea about this error but now I do because I googled it. Reading a couple of pages with examples is all it takes to understand what the error means.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Like, [this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=SPF+error+gmail)?

Answer (score 0):

SPF is a method of preventing email address spoofing. It uses special DNS entries which can be looked up by receiving email servers. These entries list the valid senders... by ip, hostmask, or a number of other ways (IP is the most reliable).

For example (using one of my own domains):

```
[wolferz.DestyNovaMk4] ➤ dig TXT scrapironcity.net

; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P3 <<>> TXT scrapironcity.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36605
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;scrapironcity.net.             IN      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
scrapironcity.net.      38400   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx a:scrapironcity.net a:unipuma.scrapironcity.net a:annapuma.scrapironcity.net ip4:74.208.200.114 ip4:82.165.21.58 ~all"

;; Query time: 128 msec
;; SERVER: 10.5.0.200#53(10.5.0.200)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 07 00:41:45 CST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 188
```

This SPF record indicates that the following sources are valid mail servers from which to receive emails ending in `@scarpironcity.net`:

hostnames (`a:`):

- `scrapironcity.net`
- `annapuma.scrapironcity.net`
- `unipuma.scrapironcity.net`

IP Adresses (`ipv4:`):

- `74.208.200.114`
- `82.165.21.58`

As well as any server listed as an MX for the `scrapironcity.net` domain (`mx`) or any ip in the domain (`a`).

The last value indicates what the requested response by receiving email servers is. Namely `~all` which means "all failed authentications (`all`) should be accepted, but marked as spam (`~`)". Receiving email servers are under no obligation to follow this request. You can read more about SPF syntax [here](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)

You need to check your DNS and make sure you have good SPF records. You might consider changing `-all` to `~all`, despite `~all` being intended for transitional use only (Google recomends using `~all` for domains used with their google apps service).